# Symfony 2 - FOSUserBundle - Added field doesn't appear in form

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I added a field to the user entity following those instructions : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html But the added attribut doesn'nt appears in the form...

My type form :

```
<?php

namespace PCUserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('realName');
}

public function getParent() {
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

public function getName() {
    return 'pc_user_registration';
}

}
```

in app config

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: PCUserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            name: pc_user_registration
```

My extended entity user

```
<?php

 // src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

 namespace PCUserBundle\Entity;

 use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
  */
 class User extends BaseUser {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
 */
protected $realName;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}

/**
 * Set realName
 *
 * @param string $realName
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setRealName($realName) {
    $this->realName = $realName;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get realName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRealName() {
    return $this->realName;
}

}
```

in the service file of my bundle :

```
services:
app.form.registration:
    class: PCUserBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: pc_user_registration }
```

The form appears but without the field real name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app config file, try this:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
```